# find the value of $\int_{C} Pdx + Qdy ?$

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

let $S= \{(x,y) | x^2 +y^2 >0 \}$ and let  $$P(x,y) = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} , Q(x,y) = \frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}$$ where  $(x,y) \in S $. Let $C$ be a piecewise smooth Jordan curve lying in  $S$

If $(0,0)$ is inside  $C$ then find the line integral $\int_{C}  Pdx + Qdy $

My attempt :  By using the green theorem $$\int_{C}  Pdx + Qdy =\int \int_{R}( \frac {dq}{dx} - \frac{dp}{dy}) dxdy= \int \int_{R} \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2 +y^2)^2 } -\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2 +y^2)^2 }dxdy=0$$

Is its true ?

Comment: To use Green's theorem you need your region to be simply connected...is this the case? Well...and the value of the integral is **not** zero.

Comment: Your calculations are wrong because Green's theorem doesn't apply here. In fact, $\int_C Pdx + Qdy = 2\pi$.

Comment: If $(0,0)$ is outside the contour, what you have done is correct.  If $(0,0)$ is inside the contour you cannot apply Greens theorem.  However, you can say that all paths will evaluate to be equal, so chose the one that is simplest to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Draw a little circle around $0$ inside of $C$. Connect that circle to $C$ by a simple curve (a line segment is generally sufficient). The region between the circle, $C$, and the curve is simply connected.